# How to access public const LINE_DOUBLE using string of library phppresentation

Tags: php, phppresentation

i want to access LINE_DOUBLE from the Border Library of phppresentation using string "LINE_DOUBLE"
have tried using constant() but no luck any other solution will be very helpful

```
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\PhpPresentation;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Alignment;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Bullet;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Color;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Border;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Fill;

 public function addLine($val)
        {
          $border = new Border;
          $str = "LINE_DOUBLE";
          $lineShape = $this->currentSlide->createLineShape($val["startX"],$val["startY"],$val["endX"],$val["endY"]);
          $lineShape->getBorder()
          ->setLineStyle(constant("$border::$str"))
          ->setLineWidth($val["width"])
          ->getColor()->setARGB($val["lineColor"]);     
        }
```

Comment: Can you try `$border::{$str}`

Comment: tried already not working

Comment: @user15398154 Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: @user15398154 You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952904/php-constant-not-working-with-namespace

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways

1. Using `constant()` function

```php
->setLineStyle(constant("Border::{$str}"))
```

`$border` is an object not class and to access the Class constant, you need Class instead of it's object

2. Using `Reflection`

```php
$ref = new ReflectionClass('Border');
->setLineStyle($ref->getConstant($str));
```

Let me know, if either of them works or not

Comment: sorry but either of them is not working

Comment: can you check what is the output `echo constant("Border::{$str}")` or `echo $ref->getConstant($str);`

Comment: no output nothing is shown

Comment: Which version of `PHPOffice` you're using?

Comment: Am using PHPOffice `v1.17.1` and there is no `LINE_DOUBLE` constant in `Border` class. Please check you're using valid constant or not

Comment: i have dowlnoaded it recently using composer.json file version is 0.6.0

Comment: As I mentioned, there is no such constant in the latest version

Comment: But if i avoid using string and just type ->setLineStyle(Border::LINE_DOUBLE); it is working that means there is a constant with that name

Comment: Can you please share PHPOffice library version from `composer.json` or `composer.lock` file

Answer (score 0):

Just provide the full specified path of the obejct
$str = "LINE_DOUBLE";
->setLineStyle(constant("PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Border::$str"))